# Combine Two MySQL Queries and Subtract the Results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My first query returns an average from a single week:

```
SELECT POSITION, PLAYER, SUM( POINTS ) / COUNT( DISTINCT YEAR, WEEK ) AS  'avg' 
FROM SCHEDULE WHERE WEEK = 1 GROUP BY PLAYER HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT YEAR, WEEK ) >2 
ORDER BY avg DESC
```

My second query returns an overall average:

```
SELECT POSITION, PLAYER, SUM( POINTS ) / COUNT( DISTINCT YEAR, WEEK ) AS  'avg' 
FROM SCHEDULE GROUP BY PLAYER HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT YEAR, WEEK ) >2 
ORDER BY avg DESC
```

I'm hoping to subtract query 1 from query 2 and display the results in descending order.

Comment: You want to subtract the weekly average from the overall average for each player and order by the resulting number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    WA.POSITION, 
    WA.PLAYER, 
    WA.avg as 'wk_avg',
    OA.avg as 'overall_avg',
    WA.avg - OA.avg as 'diff'
FROM 
    (SELECT POSITION, PLAYER, SUM( POINTS ) / COUNT( DISTINCT YEAR, WEEK ) AS  'avg' 
    FROM SCHEDULE WHERE WEEK = 1 GROUP BY PLAYER HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT YEAR, WEEK ) >2 
    ) WA
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT POSITION, PLAYER,SUM( POINTS ) / COUNT( DISTINCT YEAR, WEEK ) AS  'avg' 
    FROM SCHEDULE GROUP BY PLAYER HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT YEAR, WEEK ) >2 
    ) OA
ON WA.POSITION = OA.POSITION and WA.PLAYER = OA.PLAYER
ORDER BY WA.avg - OA.avg DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
SELECT m.POSITION, m.PLAYER, (m.Overallavg - m.WeeklyAvg) AS NewValue
FROM
(
  SELECT s1.POSITION, s1.PLAYER, SUM(s1.POINTS)/COUNT(DISTINCT s1.YEAR, s1.WEEK) AS Overallavg,
  (
    SELECT SUM(s2.POINTS)/COUNT(DISTINCT s2.YEAR, s2.WEEK)
    FROM SCHEDULE s2
    WHERE WEEK = 1 AND s2.PLAYER = S1.PLAYER
  ) AS WeeklyAvg
  FROM SCHEDULE s1
  GROUP BY s1.PLAYER 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s1.YEAR, s1.WEEK) > 2 
) m
ORDER BY (Overallavg - WeeklyAvg) DESC
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked. Tweeked a bit so the number came out positive.

Comment: After looking over the data a bit more I noticed this doesn't take into account that at least two week 1 results are required.

Answer (score 0):

The except operator would be a way but mysql doesnt accept it.

I did this query using NOT IN...

```
SELECT 
    S1.POSITION, S1.PLAYER, SUM( S1.POINTS ) / COUNT( DISTINCT S1.YEAR, S1.WEEK ) AS  'S1AVG' 
FROM 
    SCHEDULE S1 WHERE (S1.POSITION, S1.PLAYER, S1AVG) NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            S2.POSITION, S2.PLAYER, SUM( S2.POINTS ) / COUNT( DISTINCT S2.YEAR, S2.WEEK ) AS  'S2AVG' 
        FROM 
            SCHEDULE S2 WHERE S2.WEEK = 1 GROUP BY S2.PLAYER HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT S2.YEAR, S2.WEEK ) > 2 
        ORDER BY S2AVG DESC
    ) 
GROUP BY S1.PLAYER 
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT S1.YEAR, S1.WEEK ) > 2 
ORDER BY S1AVG DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work in MySQL

`SELECT @result = (QUERY1) - (QUERY2)`

Or like this

`SELECT (QUERY1) - (QUERY2)`